# Limitar checkbox jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter, checkbox

galera eu to criando um sistema onde listo imagens do banco e abaixo de cada imagem tem um checkbox, tudo isso dentro de um for para pegar as imagens do banco, queria uma função para poder limitar a quantidade de checkbox ou seja fotos que o usuário pode selecionar, estou utilizando o CI, segue a view

```
        <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="select">
                    <h4 class="info-text"> Selecione suas <b>10</b> fotos: </h4>
                    <div class="row">
                    <?php foreach ($for_fotos as $dados) : ?>
                      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                          <img src="<?php echo base_url($dados['path'].'/'.$dados['nome']); ?>" alt="<?php echo $dados['nome'] ?>">
                          <div class="caption">
                            <p>
                              <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                  <input class="limited" type="checkbox" value="">
                                  Selecionar
                                </label>
                              </div>
                            </p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>  
                    <?php endforeach; ?>  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wizard-footer">
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <input type='submit' class='btn btn-next btn-fill btn-warning btn-wd btn-sm' value='PRÓXIMO' />
                        <!--<input type='button' class='btn btn-finish btn-fill btn-warning btn-wd btn-sm' name='finish' value='Finish' />-->
                    </div>
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <?php echo anchor('selecao/voltar', 'Voltar', 'class="btn btn-previous btn-fill btn-default btn-wd btn-sm"'); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <?php echo form_close(); ?> 
    </div>
```

Também vou deixar a scren para vocês acompanharem
[image: scren da tela]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bem, você pode contar o número de checkboxes marcados utilizando o jQuery e em seguida comparar com o valor limite definido e bloquear a ação do usuário da seguinte maneira.

```
$(document).on('click', '.limited', function(){
   var limit = 2;
   var counter = $('.limited:checked').length;
   if(counter > limit) {
      this.checked = false;
      alert('Limite atingido');
   }
});
```

**Exemplo:** https://jsfiddle.net/0mj39ksx/2/

Comment: utilizei a função e setei o limite para 1 mais não aconteceu, joguei o código na própria view para teste e deveria funcionar

Comment: Olá. Infelizmente postei o código com erro na primeira vez, teste novamente para ver o que acontece. Coloquei também um exemplo no JSFiddle.

Comment: O código estava certo apenas dei uma modifica e funcionou.